# Textbox image missing after re-focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, onblur, onfocus

May i know how can i remain the text box image when the textbox is re-focus ? the textbox was validated which when user no fill up the value in the textbox it will appear error message and start focus on the textbox. Unfortunately after the textbox is re-focus the image is missing. Please help check my following demo with my current coding. Any help would be appreciated.

Example : [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/17584/) `1`

Comment: The `background` property is overriding the `background-image: url(http://ran.ge/content/uploads/2009/11/logo-trimmed.png);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **error_function** you're overriding the input background property.
You should use backgroundColor property:

```
document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundColor           = "#FDEBEB";
```

Comment: Great! Thanks you @Bellu, what a silly mistake i've done.

Answer (score 1):

I have add some line of jquery to your `code`, see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/17586/) and hope it work for you

```
    function fnName(ID, name) {
    if (name == "") {
        error_function("** Please enter the Name.", ID, "errMsg");
    } else {

        release_function(ID, "errMsg");
    }
}

function error_function(message, ID, labelID) {

    document.getElementById(labelID).innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById(labelID).style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.background = "#FDEBEB";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.border = "thin solid red";
    document.getElementById(ID).value = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).focus();

}

function release_function(ID, labelID) {
    document.getElementById(labelID).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(labelID).style.display = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.border = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundColor = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundImage = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundSize = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundPosition = "";
    document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundRepeat = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks you @henry varro, this applicable too.